# Use "Touch -r" for several files with automator

Tags: shell, terminal, osx-yosemite, automator

I use "MacOS X Yosemite (10.10.4)"

I've converted video mts files to mov files using QuickTime, but the new file created doesn't preserve original Creation Date.

> fileA.mts --> Creation Date: 07/02/2010 10:51
>
> fileA_converted.mov --> Creation Date: Today 8:35

I'd like to change the Creation Date attribute of several files, using the date of the original files. I know I can do this by using Terminal "Touch" command in order to this:

```
touch -r fileA.mts fileA_converted.mov

touch -r fileB.mts fileB_converted.mov
```

As I have more than 200 files to change Creation Date, is it possible to automate this using automator Script Shell action, or any other way?

Comment: Are the files all in the same directory?

Comment: Yes. All files are in the same folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this in the `bash` shell - which is what you get in `Terminal` (untested):

```
#!/bin/bash
for orig in *.mts; do 
   # Generate new name from old one
   new="${orig/.mts/_converted.mov}"
   echo touch -r "$orig" "$new"
done
```

Save the above in a file called `doDates` and then type this in the Terminal

```
chmod +x doDates          # make the script executable
./doDates                 # run the script
```

**Sample output**

```
touch -r Freddy Frog.mts Freddy Frog_converted.mov
touch -r fileA.mts fileA_converted.mov
```

At the moment it does nothing, but run it, see if you like what it says, and then remove the word `echo` and run it again if all looks ok.

Comment: ThankU Mark. I get this literaly: touch -r *.mts *.mov

Comment: I only generate the new name for the `touch` command - I do not generate a file.

Comment: Ok. I get this: touch -r *.mts *.mov - and the response is "touch: *.mts: no such file or directory"

Comment: I suspect you are not calling/running it as I intended. I have updated the instructions to be more helpful :-)

Comment: I tryed again: User:Prueba User$ ./doDates
touch -r *.mts *.mov
I get the same as before. Touch -r command doesn't seem to work with * within the first argument

Comment: I see - you are not in a directory where there are any `mts` files! You need to change directory to wherever your `mts` files are - currently it can't find them. So, if your `mts` files are on your Desktop, you need to do `cd Desktop`.

Comment: MTS was in capital letters, so I've tested again and I get what you say but nothing happens with the Creation Date

Comment: Like I said, there were no `mts` files! They are `MTS` files. You will need to change the line with `new=...` into `new="${orig/.MTS/_converted.mov}"`. Then if that looks good, remove the word `echo` and run again. I would make a backup copy first.

Comment: I am in a test folder with 4 files just to test. This is what I get: User:Prueba User$ ./doDates
touch -r fileA.MTS fileA.mov -
touch -r fileB.MTS fileB.mov

Answer (score 0):

Execute below command when we have all original and converted files in same folder

```
ls | grep ".mts" | awk -F. '{print $0" "$1"_converted.mov"}' |  xargs touch -r
```

when we have different folder run below command on path where .mts files are present and add absolute path before $1 just like I have added /home/convertedfiles/

```
ls | grep ".mts" | awk -F. '{print $0" /home/convertedfiles/"$1"_converted.mov"}' |  xargs touch -r
```

Comment: Nothing happens when I use first command. All files are in the same folder

Comment: You means to say the modification time is not changed for converted files. Right? Please check the file names. Or give the original and converted file names only